# Can't test subscription upgrade/downgrade using iOS Sandbox auto renewable subscription

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit

As per apple document now user can test plan upgrade/downgrade in sandbox mode for auto-renewable subscription. Now All Plans of same subscription group is appearing in manage subscription page in sandbox Mode. But when you try to upgrade/downgrade plan it is asking password for your actual apple id (not the sandbox test user).It is not deducting any money, because it is in sandbox mode, but the problem is UI is not reflecting the upgraded/downgraded plan in sandbox mode. It displays same plan as before upgrade/downgrade. Also nothing is changed in receipt info also(any transaction not added).I have also added transaction observer in my app that is also not showing any transaction with new transaction id? Is this the bug in the apple sandbox mode testing process?.Has anybody able to test this in sandbox mode?

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using iOS  14.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to upgrade/downgrade plan from setting application manage subscription screen, it seems like apple does not support it till now in sandbox mode. So I have implemented upgrade/downgrade functionality within the application and  when plan is upgraded/downgraded within the application it is reflected in manage subscription page and i got transaction entries by verifying receipt

Comment: Hi, @iosdev1111 can you provide the code to upgrade and downgrade the subscription? I am searching the docs, not exactly sure how to do it. It helps a lot.